# Zoom in on SSRS 2008 R2 Spatial Map

Tags: dictionary, ssrs-2008, spatial

Is it possible to zoom in on a map which has already been generated in SSRS 2008 R2?

I can see how to set the zoom level at design time, but not at run time

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a "no".

All the examples I've seen talk about links on the map (e.g. on a point) which when clicked basically show another report, which happens to be at a different zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is set the zoom level to a parameter with values of different zoom levels.  It doesn't let you zoom anywhere on the map, but it typically will zoom in on the point. Personally, I have been a little disappointed with the lack of interactivity with the mapping in SSRS 2008.

Comment: how can you add zoom level to parameters?

Comment: You can modify the zoom level by right clicking the map and selecting "Viewport Properties" --> Select "Center and Zoom" on the left and for the "Zoom level (percent):" it defaults to "Auto", you can set this value to a parameter.  In my test example, I simply added a scale of available values ( Lowest = 100, Low = 500 ...Street View 40000).  Not as user friendly as what we are usually used to in web maps, but does provide some interactivity.

Comment: how can you do it during run time? I want to set zoom level as a filter

Comment: Create a parameter (@Zoom)
Set the value of the Zoom Level  (found in previous comment) to @Zoom.  So at run time, the end user can enter (or select) a zoom level.

Comment: It didn't work :(, please update me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830380/showing-zoom-level-in-a-textbox-in-ssrs-2008-r2

Answer (score 0):

create a Parameter @Zoom,
then you can replace value of  tag

```
<MapCustomView>
        <CenterX>34.6386680603027</CenterX>
        <CenterY>42.2658576965332</CenterY>
        <Zoom>229.739669799805</Zoom>
```

with =Parameters!Zoom.Value in code file.

```
<MapCustomView>
        <CenterX>34.6386680603027</CenterX>
        <CenterY>42.2658576965332</CenterY>
        <Zoom>=Parameters!Zoom.Value</Zoom>
```

now use a filter to enter the amount manually.