# zoom in SSRS 2008 R2 MAP during Runtime

Tags: ssrs-2008

how can you display Zoom value in a textbox in SSRS report page?
my code is like this:

```
<ReportSection>
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Map Name="Map2">
        <MapViewport>
          <MapCustomView>
            <CenterX>34.6386680603027</CenterX>
            <CenterY>42.2658576965332</CenterY>
            <Zoom>229.739669799805</Zoom>
          </MapCustomView>
        </MapViewport>
      </Map>
    </ReportItems>  
  </Body>
</ReportSection>
```

Comment: Replace:
<Zoom>229.739669799805</Zoom>

with:

<Zoom>=Parameters!Zoom.Value</Zoom>

Comment: I have a Point Layer on my map, but it will disappear while run time, and I can just see Tile Layer :(

Comment: I used Embed Layer and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<Zoom>229.739669799805</Zoom>
```

with:

```
<Zoom>=Parameters!Zoom.Value</Zoom>
```