# Zooming Properties for Bing map in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, bing

I have created an SSRS reports in which i'm using map along with bing map.
    while I'm designing i can able to zoom in and zoom out but i can't able to zoom in or out in the report preview.
    Kindly suggest how to include the zooming properties in SSRS Reports preview

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported "out-of-the-box" as of SQL 2012.  The closest I've gotten is to have a Zoom parameter and feed it into the MapViewPort / View / Zoom property.  It's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Hi below are a some other pages relating to you question
[This stackoverflow question has a discussion regarding it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412779/zoom-in-on-ssrs-2008-r2-spatial-map)  
[On this webpage there is step by step to implement the zoom using a parameter.](http://abc-techblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/ssrs-dynamic-zoom-for-maps-in-reporting.html)  
[The gentleman on this posting is using a custom webpage wrapped around an SSRS control to add panning and zoom](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1108101&printmode=false&page=2)